# Meaning of given character

Tags: kanji, kana

I was just wondering the character shown in image is Japanese or not. If yes then can you please tell me the meaning of it.

[image]

Comment: I'd agree with what others are saying: it looks very much like a stylistic 隼（はやぶさ）. In fact, here's a screen dump of the image with JWPce showing the Kanji detail next to it: http://taylorj.org.uk/images/Hayabusa.png

Comment: @jkerian. Whoops looks like I got the names wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be 隼（はやぶさ）- falcon? Pretty certain about the top part, less sure about the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it says the same as the romaji directly below it, painted on the side of the bike: http://www.suzukicycles.com/Product%20Lines/Cycles/Products/Hayabusa/2012/GSX1300R.aspx

The literal meaning can be looked up in any of the dictionaries listed on [our resources page](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese), [like this](http://jisho.org/words?jap=hayabusa&eng=&dict=edict) for example.